# What does this vim script do?

Tags: vimrc

I'm trying to deconstruct a `.vimrc` file to learn. I'm at a loss to determine what this does. Typing the `]` and `_$` mapped keys in visual mode doesn't seem to do anything useful. Maybe I'm missing something.

```
vmap <silent>       ]   $"yygv_$
vmap <silent><expr> _$  Under_dollar_visual()

function! Under_dollar_visual ()
    " Locate block being shifted...
    let maxcol = max(map(split(@y, "\n"), 'strlen(v:val)')) + getpos("'<")[2] - 2

    " Return the selction that does the job...
    return maxcol . '|'
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vmap <silent>       ]   $"yygv_$
```

This selects to the end of the line (`$`), copies everything to the `@y` register (`"yy`), visually selects the block (`gv`) and then calls `_$`.

```
vmap <silent><expr> _$  Under_dollar_visual()
```

`<expr>` means that the result of the expression is evaluated (see `help map-expression`).

In `Under_dollar_visual`, `maxcol` is set to

```
let maxcol = max(map(split(@y, "\n"), 'strlen(v:val)'))
```

the longest line of the text in the `@y` register that was just copied

```
+ getpos("'<")[2] - 2
```

plus the start column of the block minus two (without the last character).

```
return maxcol . '|'
```

Finally it returns the keys that will be evaluated by vim (`|` = To screen column [count]).

For example if you select a visual-block (indicated by X)

```
aaaXXXyyy
aaaXXXyyyy
aaaXXXyyyyy
```

and press `]`, you'll get:

```
aaaXXXXXX
aaaXXXXXXX
aaaXXXXXXXy
```

(if the cursor was on the last line) which is the same as if you had typed `10|` with the initial selection.

Comment: also, I think `<silent>` means *dont show the command output in the command line area*